# how to export data to mainframe from hadoop

Tags: hadoop, export, sqoop, mainframe

Is there a way to export data from hadoop to mainframe using sqoop. I am pretty new to mainframe.
I understand that we can sqoop in the data from mainframe to hadoop. I skimmed through the sqoop documentation but doesnt say anything about export

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to cover export:  https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal

While I've not used sqoop, it appears to use a JDBC connection to a mainframe database. If you have that and the mainframe data table is already created (note in the doc: "The target table must already exist in the database."), then you should be able to connect to the mainframe database as the export destination. Many mainframe data sources (e.g. Db2 z/OS) support this.

Comment: Thanks for the help!